# Placing a json response with nested value in a Java POJO

Tags: java, json, gson, cucumber, pojo

I have an API POST endpoint which returns a json object structured like so:

- Data (the original data I sent up)
- JsonAPI (The version of JSON API the endpoint is conforming to)
- Status (The status of the call to the endpoint)
- Message (Used in case of a schema validation error)

All of these are stored in the following POJO using GSON fromJson():

```
package json.responses;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

public class SupplierResponseTest {

    private StatusResponse status;
    private JsonElement jsonapi;
    private String message;
    private JsonElement data;


    public SupplierResponseTest(StatusResponse status, JsonElement jsonapi) {
        this.status = status;
        this.jsonapi = jsonapi;

    }
    public SupplierResponseTest(StatusResponse status, JsonElement jsonapi, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.jsonapi = jsonapi;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public SupplierResponseTest(StatusResponse status, JsonElement jsonapi, JsonElement data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.jsonapi = jsonapi;
        this.data = data;

    }
    public StatusResponse getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public JsonElement getJsonapi() {
        return jsonapi;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public JsonElement getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

As you can see I currently store the jsonapi value as a `JsonElement`. This means that when I parse the value from the json I end up with the string value being `{"version":"1.0"}`.

My aim is to store this value as a sub(?) object. And, rather than the api value being a `JsonElement` within SupplierResponseTest, for it to be an object or an enum. However, I'm stuck as to how to do this.

The purpose of storing the value this way is to be able to perform cucumber validation on the new object's value which would be `1.0`, rather than parsing a bunch of json `{"version":"1.0"}`.

The cucumber I'm using is:

```
Scenario Outline: Add Supplier Details
    Given the system does not know about any Suppliers
    When the client adds the following <supplier>
    Then the response status is <status>
    And the response has the <jsonapi> version
    And the response has the request <supplier>

        Examples:
        | supplier                  | status    | jsonapi   |
        | "Blue Network Energy LTD" | "SUCCESS" | "1.0"     |
```

The specific step definition I'm having issues with is:

```
@Then("^the response has the \"([^\"]*)\" version$")
public void the_response_has_the_version(String arg1) throws Throwable {

    try{            

        //This returns a string of json...
        JsonElement apiVersion = supplierResponse.getJsonapi();

        //The below attempts to assert the two values "1.0" and {"version":"1.0"} 
        Assert.assertEquals(arg1, apiVersion.toString());

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I took the lead from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947159/using-gson-to-elegantly-handle-nested-json-objects?rq=1).

I created a new class which covers the nested json element:

```
package json.responses;
public class ApiVersionResponseTest { 

    private String version;

    private ApiVersionResponseTest(String version) { 
        this.version = version;
    }


    public String getApiVersion() {
        return version;
    }

}
```

the parent class constructors were changed to allow the apiversion to be passed and created as a new object:

```
package json.responses;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

public class SupplierResponseTest {

    private StatusResponseTest status;
    private ApiVersionResponseTest jsonapi; //Relevant change
    private String message;
    private JsonElement data;


    public SupplierResponseTest(StatusResponseTest status, ApiVersionResponseTest jsonapi) {
        this.status = status;
        this.jsonapi = jsonapi;

    }
    public SupplierResponseTest(StatusResponseTest status, ApiVersionResponseTest jsonapi, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.jsonapi = jsonapi;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public SupplierResponseTest(StatusResponseTest status, ApiVersionResponseTest jsonapi, JsonElement data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.jsonapi = jsonapi;
        this.data = data;

    }
    public StatusResponseTest getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public ApiVersionResponseTest getJsonapi() {
        return jsonapi;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public JsonElement getData() {
        return data;
    }   
}
```

And the step definition (now working) calls the nested object like so:

```
@Then("^the response has the \"([^\"]*)\" version$")
public void the_response_has_the_version(String arg1) throws Throwable {

    try{            

        Assert.assertEquals(arg1, supplierResponse.getJsonapi().getApiVersion());

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Bingo bango. Fixed.